# Easy formula for coordinates of point with minimum distance to other fixed points

Tags: geometry

If you have the coordinates of 3 or more points in a 2D plane, how do you find the point that minimizes the total distance from that point to the other points? Also, is there a formula for this that can be easily memorized and used quickly in math competitions such as the AMC or AIME? I looked here ([minimizing sum of distances](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58868/minimizing-sum-of-distances)) but I couldn't the exact formula that I was looking for.

I am aware that the point I am looking for is called the Fermat point but Wikipedia is not offering much other than a formula involving vectors, which I won't likely have the time or skill to use on competition day.

Comment: For three points, this is known as the [Fermat Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point?wprov=sfti1).

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that.

Comment: It is almost sure that no such formula exists. Even in the 3 points case, the coordinates of the so-called "Fermat point" are not given by a formula.

Comment: @JeanMarie It appears to be as such.

Comment: The problem is rather easy to solve for any number of points but the explcit formula does not exist. If you are interested by the method, let me know.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Please do let me know.

Comment: Have a look at my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453660/find-the-x-y-location-of-one-point-unknown-location-in-space-with-respect-to-f/3454103#3454103 . If it is not clear, just tell. Cheers :-)

Comment: You might find the article Man versus computer, The Mathematical Gazette, Vol 91, 522, Nov 2007 of interest. This gives a coordinate system based upon the Fermat point (which therefore has position vector $<0,0,0>$). In terms of this system many results about triangles take a nice form - however, it might not be useful for a competition where the markers may well be unfamiliar with the method.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I understand your answer thank you so much!